# Передача строки из Receiver в MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне правильно передать строку из Receiver в MainActivity и в остальные классы, есть ресирвер который принимает данные, подставляет их в строку и должен передать в другие 3 класса, но передает строку только в один или максимум два класса, в третий не дает, как исправить данный код? Программа используется на ТСД, лазер считывает штрих или DataMatrix код.

```
public class ScanTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "ScanTestReceiver";
private NotificationManager mNm = null;
private static final String SCANKEY = ScanUtil.SCANKEY;
private static final String SCAN_DECODING_BROADCAST = ScanUtil.SCAN_DECODING_BROADCAST;
public String scancode, keycode;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
            String v = intent.getStringExtra(key);
            Log.d("~~~~~myApplication", "~~~~~" + key + " is a key in the bundle with value " + v);
        }
        int scanKey = intent.getIntExtra(SCANKEY, -1);
        mNm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (SCAN_DECODING_BROADCAST.equals(action) /* && isScanKeyEnable(context,scanKey) */) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ScanTestService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            scancode = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_BARCODE_DECODING_SYMBOLE");
            keycode = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_BARCODE_DECODING_DATA");

            Log.i(TAG, "Сработало событие EXTRA_BARCODE_DECODING_DATA__" + scancode + "_" + scanKey + "_" + keycode);

            if (scancode.equals("Code 128")) {
            try {

                MainActivity  .getInstace().updateTheTextView(scancode+ "_" + keycode);
                ScanPriemSKoles .getInstace().updateTheTextView(scancode+ "_" + keycode);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            } else if (scancode.equals("Data Matrix")) {
                try {
            MainActivity  .getInstace().updateTheTextView(scancode+ "_" + keycode);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Matrix------------------------------------для приема на склад" + action);
            RetirementScan  .getInstace().updateTheTextView(scancode+ "_" + keycode);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Matrix------------------------------------для выдачи в отделения" + action);
            ScanPriemSKoles .getInstace().updateTheTextView(scancode+ "_" + keycode);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Matrix------------------------------------для выдачи с колес" + action);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            } else {
                try {
                    MainActivity  .getInstace().updateTheTextView( "Ошибка_1");
                    RetirementScan  .getInstace().updateTheTextView( "Ошибка_1");
                   // ScanPriemSKoles .getInstace().updateTheTextView( "Ошибка_1");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            ToneGenerator ToneGenerator1 = new ToneGenerator(STREAM_MUSIC, 30);
            ToneGenerator1.startTone(TONE_DTMF_6, 100);
    }
}
```

}

код MainActivity

```
public static MainActivity  getInstace(){
    return ins;
}

public void updateTheTextView(final String t) {

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            String[] words = t.split("_");
            for(String word : words) {
            }

            x = words[0];
            z = words[1];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Подскажите, Ваши 3 класса, в которые вы хотите передать данные - наследники каких классов? 
Если это наследники класса Activity/AppCompatActivity/FragmentActivity, то создавать единственный инстанс на всё приложение для Activity и держать его в памяти чревато утечками памяти и передачей данный в устаревший объект. В таком случае надо передавать данные через Bundle.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, остальные так же

Comment: Попробуйте сохранять данные при получении в базу данных (например с помощью Room). А потом через LiveData подписаться на изменение этих данных. Тогда получится всё очень красивенько. Room: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html. LiveData: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/27-course/architecture-components/525-urok-2-livedata.html

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)